# Add column to Excel

Tags: c#, streamwriter

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"" + textBox2.Text + @"\" + filename.TrimStart() + ".csv", true))  

          {

           if (!exists)
           {
             writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
             writer.WriteLine("REG.,BR.,BR.NAME,AC TYPE,PRODUCT,NO.OF ACS,ORG.CURRENCY BALANCE,ORG CURRENCY,BALANCE LKR");
             writer.WriteLine(text.Replace("|", ","));
           }
            writer.WriteLine(text.Replace("|", ","));
```

////true is append parameter. I use this code to create Excel files. I want add new column and fill each cell with auto increment numbers.

Comment: what is it you actually need? what are you trying to do and what error if any are you getting or is this a question to debug your code?

Comment: i need add new column to my excell sheet friend..

Comment: youre writing a CSV file am i correct?

Comment: @SimonPrice 'filename.TrimStart() + ".csv", true)) '   I would say yes he writes to a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't include the appropriate infos I take it that text includes all lines that you want to use and , is being used as the separator instead of the more commonly used ; .

The following splits this complete text into multiple lines and creates an "autoincrement" number that is appended as the last column.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"" + textBox2.Text + @"\" + filename.TrimStart() + ".csv", true))  

{

    if (!exists)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        writer.WriteLine("REG.,BR.,BR.NAME,AC TYPE,PRODUCT,NO.OF ACS,ORG.CURRENCY BALANCE,ORG CURRENCY,BALANCE LKR");
    }

    var textArray = text.Replace("|", ",").split(Environment.NewLine);
    int number = 0;

    foreach (string text in textArray)
    {
        number ++;
        write.WriteLine(text + "," + number.ToString());
    }
```